# Distributed processing with Apache Ignite queues

Tags: java, distributed-computing, ignite

Consider the following scenario. I have a cluster of Apache Ignite nodes. On each node, work units can appear (e.g. based on input of end users) that need be processed asynchronously. The order of execution is not strictly important, i.e. work units that occurred early in time should be executed before later work units but only approximately.

After some reading, my first thought was to use a [distributed queue](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/queue-and-set) (collocated because it could be big). Each node would have one worker thread listening to the queue and processing work units once they arrive. However, as far as I understand, queue items are distributed to all cluster nodes then.

So my second thought was: Is there a way to keep work units arising on a node on that node and being processed mainly on that node? I mean, when node local work units are all processed then work units from other nodes are taken etc.

Did you encounter a similar problem and how did you solve it?

**EDIT**: Work units need to be persistent in my case. That means, if a node is shutdown during execution of a work unit then the work unit must be processed by other node or re-processed on node restart.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a use case for Compute Grid functionality: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/compute-grid

Specifically, you might be interested in job stealing: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/load-balancing#job-stealing

Comment: This is a great hint, compute grid and job stealing sounds like what I need. So you would use IgniteCompute#call to trigger execution of a work unit? It won't be persistent, right (if the initiating node is dropped, then the work unit is dropped)? In my case work units need to be persistent when nodes fail (sorry, I didn't mention in my question, I will edit).

Comment: @SteffenHarbich The initiating node sends the task for servers and awaits the result. If it goes down, who should be getting the result?

Comment: @Dmitriy My use case is different. The enduser clicks a button (like fire-and-forget, with no immediate result), the work unit is enqueued but must be done at some time in future (persistent). There is no direct result for the user.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich Well, in that case I would recommend deploying an Ignite singleton service that would store all executing tasks in a cache and then periodically check if the originating node failed. If it failed, then retry it. More in Ignite services here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/service-grid